# Difference current month / month a year back on customer level in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, date-difference

I am trying to calculate the sales volume difference between a given month and the same month one year back (e.g Jan 2021 - Jan 2020). The tricky part is that it should be done on customer level. My table now looks like this:

| Date | Customer_number | Sales_Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14.01.2020 | 1111 | 1000 |
| 13.01.2020 | 2222 | 2000 |
| 21.02.2020 | 1111 | 4000 |
| 17.02.2020 | 2222 | 5000 |
| 22.01.2021 | 1111 | 1500 |
| 24.01.2021 | 2222 | 2600 |
| 19.02.2021 | 1111 | 4700 |
| 18.02.2021 | 2222 | 5800 |

And my output should look like this:

| Date | Customer_number | Sales_Volume | Volume_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14.01.2020 | 1111 | 1000 | 0 |
| 13.01.2020 | 2222 | 2000 | 0 |
| 21.02.2020 | 1111 | 4000 | 0 |
| 17.02.2020 | 2222 | 5000 | 0 |
| 22.01.2021 | 1111 | 1500 | 500 |
| 24.01.2021 | 2222 | 2600 | 600 |
| 19.02.2021 | 1111 | 4700 | 700 |
| 18.02.2021 | 2222 | 5800 | 800 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for a calculated column:

```
Column = 
VAR _y = YEAR([Date])
VAR _m = MONTH([Date])
VAR _c = [Customer_number]
VAR _tbl_prev = FILTER(ALL('Table'), [Customer_number] = _c && MONTH([Date]) = _m && YEAR([Date]) = _y - 1)
VAR _tbl_curr = FILTER(ALL('Table'), [Customer_number] = _c && MONTH([Date]) = _m && YEAR([Date]) = _y)
VAR _result = SUMX(_tbl_curr, [Sales_Volume]) - SUMX(_tbl_prev, [Sales_Volume])
RETURN IF(COUNTROWS(_tbl_prev), _result, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works perfectly ! :)

Comment: Hey, we have just modified the code to substract previous month from current month as well. However, it's not working correctly when it comes to January - December, presumably due to the different years. Could you assist me on this please ? The code is as follows:

Comment: Net change CM-PM = 

VAR _y = YEAR([AS_OF_DATE])

VAR _m = MONTH([AS_OF_DATE])

VAR _c = [CUST_NO]

VAR _tbl_prev = FILTER(ALL('Select ri_rep_table_monthly_his'), [CUST_NO] = _c && MONTH([AS_OF_DATE]) = _m -1 && YEAR([AS_OF_DATE]) = _y )

VAR _tbl_curr = FILTER(ALL('Select ri_rep_table_monthly_his'), [CUST_NO] = _c && MONTH([AS_OF_DATE]) = _m && YEAR([AS_OF_DATE]) = _y )

VAR _result = SUMX(_tbl_curr, [AVG_VOLUME_LIABILITIES]) - SUMX(_tbl_prev, [AVG_VOLUME_LIABILITIES])

RETURN IF(COUNTROWS(_tbl_prev), _result, 0)

Comment: Hi. You should create a separate question and link this one if you feel questions are related. Will be better, because this comment section lacks functionality and is not for detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below **Measure Code**-

```
your_value = 

var current_row_year = YEAR(MIN(your_table_name[Date]))
var current_row_month = MONTH(MIN(your_table_name[Date]))
var current_row_customer_number = MIN(your_table_name[Customer_number])
var current_row_sales_value = MIN(your_table_name[Sales_Volume])

var last_year_sales_volumne = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Sales_Volume]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        YEAR(your_table_name[Date]) = current_row_year - 1
        && MONTH(your_table_name[Date]) = current_row_month
        && your_table_name[Customer_number] = current_row_customer_number
    )
) + 0

RETURN IF(
    last_year_sales_volumne = 0,
    0,
    current_row_sales_value - last_year_sales_volumne
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]