# Implementing Binomial Hypothesis Testing significance tests in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, hypothesis-test

This is partly a theory question, and partly an implementation question. My stats is a little rusty...

I am developing a report that is attempting to determine if the difference in occurances between a reference group and a selected group are statistically significant.

So, for example, if something occurs in X of n tests for one group, is it statistically significant than if it 'normally' occurs at a rate of Y of m tests for a different (control) group.

So, my H0 is that the rate is Y of m, per the control group
h1 is that it is not the same as the control group. (ideally, I'd like to use a 1-tailed test, depending if the observed occurrence is greater or less than the control, but my current implementation is 2 tailed)

I'd be comfortable with a CI of 80%.

I've got (slightly pseudocode here):

```
Zscore = 
   VAR pControl = DIVIDE(COUNT([Control occurrences]), COUNT([Control Tests])) RETURN
   VAR pTest = DIVIDE(COUNT([Test occurrences]), COUNT([Test Tests])) RETURN
   VAR controlStandardError = 
      SQRT(
         DIVIDE(
            (pControl * (1-pControl)
            , COUNT([Control Tests])
          )
      ) RETURN
   VAR testStandardError = 
      SQRT(
         DIVIDE(
            (pTest* (1-pTest)
            , COUNT([Test Tests])
          )
      ) RETURN
DIVIDE(
   (pTest - pControl)
   , SQRT(POWER(testStandardError, 2) + POWER(controlStandardError, 2)
)
```

I'm then calculating:

```
p-Value = 
   VAR pControl = DIVIDE(COUNT([Control occurrences]), COUNT([Control Tests])) RETURN
   IF(pControl > 0, 
      1 - ABS(NORM.DIST(Zscore, 0, 1, TRUE)
   )
```

I am then displaying in a table each of my non-null hypotheses and filtering the table such that p-Value is less than 0.1. (2-tailed 80%)

am I on the right track here? Or have I completely bungled the theory on this one?

Comment: I am just curious... why do you put RETURN after each VAR?

Comment: That's DAX syntax. RETURN indicates the end of the VAR statement.

Comment: No no no. VAR is ok on it's own. After RETURN you simply tell what to return. Normally you will have many many VARs and only one RETURN at the end.

Comment: As an example, you can look at this recent answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797718/#66798491

Comment: This is a helpful reference for this answer:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other

Answer (score 2):

Theory and example tables - Right-tailed (μ > μ₀)

[image]

DAX

```
ControlGroup
XControl = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ControlGroup,ControlGroup[Outcome]=1))
NControl = COUNTROWS(ControlGroup)
pControl = DIVIDE([XControl],[NControl])

TreatmentGroup
XTreatment = COUNTROWS(FILTER(TreatmentGroup,TreatmentGroup[Outcome]=1)) 
NTreatment = COUNTROWS(TreatmentGroup)
pTreatment = DIVIDE([XTreatment],[NTreatment])

Test Parameters
PooledProportion = 
DIVIDE(
    [XTreatment]+[XControl],
    [NTreatment]+[NControl]
)

ZCritivalValue = NORM.S.INV(0.90)

ZValue = DIVIDE(
[pTreatment]-[pControl],
SQRT(
    [PooledProportion]*(1-[PooledProportion])*((1/[NTreatment])+(1/[NControl]))
)
)
```

Visualization (example)
[image]